# Wordpress Gravity Form CSS for checkbox

Tags: wordpress, css

i have a Wordpress form added here :     http://goo.gl/6UtIgr

on the second page of form : 
i have several checkbox groups with 2 items each.

iwant them to align on 3 col layout
so i used Ready class gf_list_3col

```
.gform_wrapper li.gfield.gf_list_3col ul.gfield_checkbox li 
{
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 8px 0;
  min-height: 1.8em;
  clear: left !important;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

but it seems to be not working.

please give a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the checkbox groups with three inputs, you'll need to remove the `float` and add in a `display: inline-block;`:

```
.gform_wrapper li.gfield.gf_list_3col ul.gfield_checkbox li {
    width: 33%;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 0 8px 0;
    min-height: 1.8em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you instead want your groups with two inputs to follow the exact same grid, you'll have to target them with `.gform_wrapper li.gfield.gf_list_2col ul.gfield_checkbox li`:

```
.gform_wrapper li.gfield.gf_list_2col ul.gfield_checkbox li {
    width: 33%;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 0 8px 0;
    min-height: 1.8em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You can obviously combine these, if you wish to target both.